# Java make an object visible across methods

Tags: java, object

I have to methods

A:

```
String teststring = new String ("blublub");
```

B:

```
System.out.println(teststring);
```

What do I have to do to that B can see that object of A?

I already tried that public || final stuff but that wasn't the right way I think.

thx for your help

whole code of the two methods

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    if (hasFocus){
        final String teststring= new String ("blubblub");
    }
}


public void a() {
    System.out.println(teststring);
}
```

Error log when putting MediaPlayer outside a method.

```
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{~.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1803)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:160)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1008)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4070)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:906)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:664)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:697)
04-06 05:20:25.140: E/AndroidRuntime(12120):    at~.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:79)
```

line 79 is: private MediaPlayer mediaPlayerW = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.soft);

around this line 79 is:

```
 button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this); }


private MediaPlayer mediaPlayerW = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.soft);
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
```

Is it possible, that it can have sth to do with getBaseContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    if (hasFocus){
        final String teststring= new String ("blubblub");
    }
}    

public void a() {
    System.out.println(teststring);
}
```

While testString is declared "in the class" it is actually declared inside of the onWindowFocusChanged method of the class, and by doing this, it is visible only inside of that method. To make it visible throughout the class, declare it in the class and not in a method or constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
   // variable below declared *in* the class
   // and is visible throughout the class
   private String testString = "";
   private String anotherVariable; // declared but not instantiated


public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    if (hasFocus){
        // don't redeclare the variable here, and don't use new String(...)
        // final String teststring= new String ("blubblub"); 

        anotherVariable = "blubblub"; // instantiated here
    }
}


   public void someMethod() {
      // variable is now visible inside of all non-static methods
      System.out.println(testString);
   }

}
```

In addition, you want to avoid using `String myString = new String("Foo");` since that can cause the possibly inefficient creation of unnecessary objects. Instead use `String myString = "foo";` which will re-use Strings from the String pool if one is available.

Comment: Thanks so far, I tried it this way ~30 minutes ago. Unfortunately the Android MediaPlayer stuff has to be executed within a method (if I understood everything correctly)

Comment: @user2161301: It can still be executed within the method as long as the variable is declared in the class. If this didn't work for you, then you will want to show this attempt and any problems it caused.

Comment: I put the "new" log in the first post

Comment: @user2161301: You will wI don't do Android programming, but it looks like something is null. Note that you can *declare* a variable in the class, and then *instantiate* it in a method. I will show you this in an edit to my answer.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! YOU ARE THE MAN! For strings it works, now I have to see if I can do the same on that media player. Thanks again

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 for perseverance  :-)

Comment: Even i am now fighting with other problems, it works now with the MediaPlayer, cool thing,  thx

Comment: @user2161301: glad you've got this problem licked. Programming is like that -- solving one problem after another. Best of luck.

Comment: Well I already have my first app with 20+ downloads/day and a few sales but it was a pretty simple one. I thought making this app I am programming now is more simple, but I got a way more problems then before.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

Simply change 'testring' to 'teststring' in the bit in brackets in **statement** B

Comment: ouch. I missed that one. 1+

Comment: It wasn't that one, i just made an error while parsing this. error still there

Comment: If line b is in the same **method** as line A, your (edited) code should work.

Comment: No A and B are different methods, that's the point. You guys complain about others sending a huge code and you complain about a simplified code :/

Comment: @user2161301: please show the *relevant* code. Best a small compilable runnable example or failing that a *near* compilable example. You assume that we can just pull the reason for your problems out of thin air without supporting facts, error messages, and such, but we can't. We can't guess at things you don't show us. We have no crystal balls.

Comment: @user2161301 your code is _too_ simplified. It leaves out the important parts. Please don't complain when we ask for them.

Comment: No no, don't misunterstand me, it was not a comlain of mine, I just didn't know whats the correct mix of those

Comment: @user2161301 the correct mix is "everything that shows your problem, and nothing else". "self-contained correct" means that it can be compiled and demonstrates your issue (or throws the compile time error that you ask about). So, always post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)